# Return multiple rows with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am in the process of learning mysqli and I am trying to query a databases and return multiple rows. I understand that a loop has to be used to return multiple rows but I have no idea how I would implement this into my code. Some help in doing this would be greatly appreciated.

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM journeys WHERE id = $id");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

if ($count == 0) {
    $journeys = 'You have no future journeys.';
} else {
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2) ) {      
        $from = $row ['origin'];
        $to = $row ['destination'];
        $date = $row ['date'];
        $hour = $row ['hour'];
        $minute = $row ['minute'];
        $journeyid = $row ['journeyid'];
```

Comment: Please do a little bit of research on your end before posting a question. A simple Googling returned me a lot of possible solutions. https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=returning%20multiple%20rows%20mysql%20php
Moreover, a stackoverflow guide on how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look up some PHP mysqli examples on the internet. [There](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) [are](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) [literally](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) [hundreds](http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65%C2%A0) out there.

Comment: Usually when you use an ID column, you do that in order to identify that unique row of data from your other entries. So I'm assuming the reason your query is only returning one row is because there really is only one entry matching your query.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
    <?php

$con=  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'your data base name');
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM journeys where id=$id");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

if ($count == 0) {
    $journeys = 'You have no future journeys.';
    echo $journeys;
} else {
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2) ) {      
        $from = $row ['origin'];
        $to = $row ['destination'];
        $date = $row ['date'];
        $hour = $row ['our'];
        $minute = $row ['minute'];
        $journeyid =$row ['journeyid'];

        echo $from.'<br>';

    }
}
```

have a look at this line echo $from; this will display what ever you have in the origin column in your database, if you want to display destination, use this as well echo $to; 
means what ever you want to display do it like this echo $variableName; it will display the result;

before you display the result it will only store it, but will not display it,

have a look i change your this line of code as well

its your code

```
if ($count == 0) {
    $journeys = 'You have no future journeys.';
    echo $journeys;// i added this line
```

i added one line, because what you are saying here that if $count is equal to zero, than $journeys='you have no future journeys'; but you are not using echo you have to use echo to display the result.

if you still have some confusion ask again, and try to google as well

Answer (score -1):

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM journeys WHERE id = $id");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$count = count($row);

if(intval($count)>0)
  {

    for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++)
        {
           $from[$i] = $row[$i]['origin'];
                 -------------------------------
                 ----------------------
        }
  }
```

Comment: Use of `count()` on mysqli result set does not produce the expected output